# Dividing a closed connected region into multiple subregions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

Suppose I have a closed connected bounded region $A$ in $R^2$ (I am not that familiar with definitions in topology, so I just use the word "region" to mean the obvious one). It's probably called a closed connected bounded set in $R^2$, is it not?

If I want to partition $A$ into $n+1$ subregions with equal area using $n$ vertical lines, where $n$ is even, how do I do that?

I mean, I am sure it can be done, but I'd like to find these exact lines. My first guess is I have to find the parametrization $(x(t),y(t))$ of the boundary, but I don't know where to go next, but my next guess is to use the concept of line integral.

I assume even $n$ since I guess it is a bit more complicated than the odd ones. Just maybe..

*feel free to change the tags

Comment: You should add some more details: do you know an equation for the boundary in the form $y=f(x)$, with $f$ regular enough? is the region convex? do you need an exact result, or just a numeric approximation? A realistic example would also be of help.

Comment: @Aretino I did not know anything about convex until you mentioned it and went on to read what it is. The region need not be convex: two arbitrary points in it are connected by a curve (not necessarily straight line) in it. If the region is closed (like a disk for example), I thought the general equation needs parametrization, not just y = f(x)? I think we can assume that the parametrization is known.